# Shell within Erlang process prints input many times

Tags: io, erlang, read-eval-print-loop, erlang-shell

I built a REPL for a language in Erlang. I run it from the shell, like so:

```
repl:main(Args).
```

It reads using `io_getchars` until it encounters a `;`, then parses and lexes it:

```
getchar(eof) -> throw(eof);
getchar([C]) -> C.
getchar() -> getchar(io:get_chars("", 1)).

read_term() ->
    case getchar() of
        $; -> ";";
        C -> [C|read_term()]
    end.
```

That's all well and good, but the interaction with the repl looks like this:

```
willow% erl -name MyName 
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V7.3  (abort with ^G)
(MyName)1> repl:main(Args).
Master is <0.39.0> in init_workers
1> map(fn(x)=x+1, '[1 2 3 4 5]);      
ap(fn(x)=x+1, '[1 2 3 4 5]);
p(fn(x)=x+1, '[1 2 3 4 5]);
(fn(x)=x+1, '[1 2 3 4 5]);
fn(x)=x+1, '[1 2 3 4 5]);
n(x)=x+1, '[1 2 3 4 5]);
(x)=x+1, '[1 2 3 4 5]);
x)=x+1, '[1 2 3 4 5]);
)=x+1, '[1 2 3 4 5]);
=x+1, '[1 2 3 4 5]);
x+1, '[1 2 3 4 5]);
+1, '[1 2 3 4 5]);
1, '[1 2 3 4 5]);
, '[1 2 3 4 5]);
 '[1 2 3 4 5]);
'[1 2 3 4 5]);
[1 2 3 4 5]);
1 2 3 4 5]);
 2 3 4 5]);
2 3 4 5]);
 3 4 5]);
3 4 5]);
 4 5]);
4 5]);
 5]);
5]);
]);
);
;
Delegated packet 0 
Delegated packet 1 
Delegated packet 2 
Delegated packet 3 
Delegated packet 4 
(2 3 4 5 6)
2>
```

I also tried:

```
read_term(Acc) ->
    case io:request(standard_io, {get_until, '', scanner, token, [1]}) of
        {ok, EndToken={';;', _}, _} -> Acc ++ [EndToken];
        {ok, Token, _} -> read_term(Acc ++ [Token]);
        {error, token} -> {error, scanning_error};
        {eof, _} -> Acc
    end.
```

And it unfortunately has the same effect.

I'd rather not see every possible right-moving slice of the string I entered. What is causing this and how can I stop it?

EDIT: If I run it as `erl -noshell -eval 'repl:main()'` from the shell instead, this printing does not happen. Why?

Comment: Did you forget to include the code?

Comment: @Dogbert whoops, my bad -- added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use `io:get_line` instead, and iterate over the received string. Then you have to decide what to do if the received string does not contain any ";"

for example:

```
1> Eval = fun(X) -> io:format("evaluation of ~p~n",[X]) end.                                            
#Fun<erl_eval.6.50752066>
2> F = fun() -> 
       R = io:get_line("Enter a string : "),
       L = string:tokens(R,";"),
       [Eval(X) || X <- L]
   end.
#Fun<erl_eval.20.50752066>
3> F().                                                                                                 
Enter a string :  map(fn(x)=x+1, '[1 2 3 4 5]);map(fn(x)=x+5, '[1 2 3 4 5]);uncomplete                                
evaluation of " map(fn(x)=x+1, '[1 2 3 4 5])"
evaluation of "map(fn(x)=x+5, '[1 2 3 4 5])"
evaluation of "uncomplete\n"
[ok,ok,ok]
4> F().                                                                 
Enter a string :  map(fn(x)=x+1, '[1 2 3 4 5]);                                       
evaluation of " map(fn(x)=x+1, '[1 2 3 4 5])"
evaluation of "\n"
[ok,ok]       
5>
```

**[edit]**

`io:get_chars/2` is taking the number of chars given as parameter from the shell input, 1 in your case, and let the rest. The shell can't know that you will invoke again the `io:get_chars/2` function, so it prints again the rest of the input string, and it does the same again and again at each call of the `read_term/0` function, it is why you see this weird behavior.

`io:get_line/2` takes the whole input from the shell and return it in a string (in erlang it is a list of integer), it is why you have a clean behavior in the shell window, then it is up to you to choose your favorite algorithm to analyze this string. I have chosen `string:tokens/2` because I try to use library functions when they exists, I think it is easier to read, and does not need documentation :o)

If you don't want to take care of possible incorrect input, you can replace the F/0 function by

```
2> F = fun() ->                               
2>     Rep = io:get_line("Enter a string : "),
2>     [L,"\n"] = string:tokens(Rep,";"),     
2>     L
2> end.
```

and it will do the same thing that your read_term/0 function (except it removes the last $;, but it checks its presence):

```
3> F().                                  
Enter a string : correct input;
"correct input"
4> F().          
Enter a string : missing semi colon
** exception error: no match of right hand side value ["missing semi colon\n"]
5> F().              
Enter a string : correct input; but extracharacters after semi colon
** exception error: no match of right hand side value ["correct input"," but extracharacters after semi colon\n"]
```

Comment: Why do I need to use `io:get_line`? And that seems trickier than handling character by character or token by token.